# Как сделать так чтобы int сохранялись и открывались по кнопке продолжить в другом activity

Tags: android-studio, android

Как сохранить эти int и сделать так чтобы они снова были открыты по нажатию кнопки продолжить в activitymain
Вот код gameactivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    rt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.r);
    mont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mon);
    nastt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nast);
    subt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    nick1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nick);
    piar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.piar);
    zbnach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zbnach);
    stream = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stream);
    cheat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheat);
     con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.con);
    osp = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.osp);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nick = intent.getStringExtra("");
    nick1.setText(nick);

    cheat.setEnabled(false);
   piar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           sub=sub+15;
           mon=mon-25;
           rt.setText("Фанаты"+r);
           subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
           nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
           mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
           IfFor();
       }
   });
    stream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sub=sub+10;
            mon=mon+(sub/2);
            nast=nast-5;
            r=r+10;
            rt.setText("Фанаты"+r);
            subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
            nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
            mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
            IfFor();
        }
    });
    zbnach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            r=r-5;
            nast=nast+6;
            rt.setText("Фанаты"+r);
            subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
            nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
            mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
            IfFor();
        }
    });
    con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            r=r+15;
            sub=sub+15;
            mon=mon-100;
            rt.setText("Фанаты"+r);
            subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
            nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
            mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
            IfFor();
        }
    });
    osp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            r=r+25;
            nast=nast-10;
            rt.setText("Фанаты"+r);
            subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
            nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
            mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
            IfFor();
        }
    });

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
    public void IfFor(){
        if (nast<=0){
            Intent i1;
            i1 = new Intent(this, LoseActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
        for (r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
            sub=sub-1;
        }
        if (mon<50){
            piar.setEnabled(false);
            con.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            piar.setEnabled(true);
            con.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (sub>=10000){
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this,"Вы достигли 10 000 подписчиков", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            t.show();
        }
        if (r<=0) {
            osp.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            osp.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

вот ActivityMain

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playb);
    form = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vvnf);
    res = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
   res.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("", form.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо на нажатие кнопки поставить сохранение.

Пример:

```
     btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                saveText();
                }});
```

Само сохранение:

```
    private void saveText() {
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, randoms.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();}
```

И загрузка:

```
  private void loadText() {

        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        randoms.setText(savedText);

    }
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял куда это, и не совсем понял это дополнение к моему коду или это ВМЕСТО моего кода. И еще один момент - не понятно что такое randoms и save text

Comment: Могу предложить почитать про sharedpreference
[Читать информацию](http://www.fandroid.info/en/urok-33-sharedpreferences-sohranenie-dannyh-v-prilozheniyah-uroki-android-studio/)

Comment: Спасибо, но я не могу понять как взять не текст из формы, а int?

Comment: @weyer я немного изменил суть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Вы сохраняете в префы только один раз, при создании активити. По нажатию на кнопки вы не исполняете код, который должен что-то соранять. Вам надо исполнить код сохранения там, где исполняется код, исполняемый при нажатии на кнопки. Т.е. код сохранения надо перенести в onClick метод нужный

Comment: Только с третьего раза дошло... Переформулируй как-нибудь третье предложение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так ведь понятно же всё написал)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я немного переформулировал вопрос, теперь он точнее обьясняет то что мне надо

Comment: @MixBab, это не "немного переформулировал" - это "полностью изменил". На изначальный вопрос вам уже ответили, задавайте другой вопрос отдельным вопросом. И постарайтесь его переформулировать - текущий совсем непонятен.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто неправильно изменил String на int